# Bind and load folders in EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices

According to Microsoft, [`Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceobject.load?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ServiceObject_Load) will load the first class properties and [`Bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.bind?view=exchange-ews-api) will bind to an existing folder and load its first class properties.

Does this mean that I do not need to load after binding to a folder?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that I do not need to load after binding to a folder?

Yes the only reason you would use Load is if you wanted to view the latest properties eg say you wanted to see the latest item count on a folder if you bind was done some time ago because your always working with a disconnected data-sets.